# Translating C code to MIPS Assembly - Using Arrays

Tags: c, assembly, translation, mips

I am working on a project and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am translating a piece of C code into MIPS Assembly Language.

The C Code is as follows:

```
int A[10];
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

while(i < 10){
    sum += A[i++];
    sum *= 2;
}
```

---

I have produced the following MIPS code

```
where $s1 is base address of A    
$s2 is sum    
$s3 is i    
s4 is 10
```

```
loop:
 beq $s3, $s4, exit     #if s3 and s4 equal, go to else
 add $t0, $s3, $s3  #2i
 add $t0, $t0, $t0  #4i
 add $s1, $s1, $t0  #A[i]
 lw $t2, 0($s1)     #t2 = A[i]
 add $s2, $s2, $t2  #sum = sum + A[i]
 addi $s3, $s3, 1   #i = i + 1
 add $s2, $s2, $s2  #sum = sum * 2
 j loop
```

While my code produces a value, it doesn't match the expected value. I have been banging my head on the desk for hours trying to see what I am doing wrong and I can't figure it out. Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Looks to me like you're changing the value of $s1 on each iteration, so you're getting A[0], A[1], A[1+2], A[1+2+3], etc.

Comment: What is the expected value exactly? Array A in your C code is uninitialised...what do you expect that code to return as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding `$t0` to `$s1` every time you loop over. As such, instead of incrementing the array pointer by 4 each time, you increment by `i*4` each time.

So, instead of getting A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3], ..., you actually get A[0], A[1], A[3], A[6], ...

My suggestion would be to remove the first two `add` instructions, and just do `add $s1, $s1, 4`.

Answer (score 1):

[Polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978756/polynomial) is right, here is a fixed version of your code:

```
.text

.globl main
main:
        li $s4 , 4
        li $s3 , 0
        la $s1 , array1
loop:
        beq $s3, $s4, exit     #if s3 and s4 equal, go to else
        lw $t2, 0($s1)     #t2 = A[i]
        add $s2, $s2, $t2  #sum = sum + A[i]
        addi $s3, $s3, 1   #i = i + 1
        add $s2, $s2, $s2  #sum = sum * 2
        addi $s1, $s1, 4   #$s1 = &(A[i++])
        move $a0, $s2
        jal print_int
        j loop
exit:
        li  $v0, 10         # Exit
        syscall

print_int:
        li    $v0, 1
        syscall
        la    $a0, space
        li    $v0, 4
        syscall
        jr    $ra


.data

array1:     .word 3, 0, 1, 2
space:      .asciiz " "
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your reply and help. Thanks!